# Analyze http MP3 Audio Stream with Python

Tags: python, audio, stream, mp3

I want to analyze an http audio MP3 stream with python.

A function shall be executed if the volume level exceeds a threshold.

I tried to use pyaudio (using this nice reference https://www.swharden.com/wp/2016-07-19-realtime-audio-visualization-in-python/) but it does not support mp3.

Is there any other library that supports streaming of mp3 and such kind of analysis?

Comment: A simple command line solution would be: 
`ffmpeg -t 10 -i  http://URLTOSTREAM -af "volumedetect" -f null /dev/null`

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a cross-platform solution, but if you're on Windows you could use a combination of packages:

1. [audioread](https://github.com/beetbox/audioread) for decoding the MP3 file to a buffer. [cross-platform]
2. [pyaudio_portaudio](https://github.com/intxcc/pyaudio_portaudio) for playing the audio buffer *and* record output of the soundcard (then doing the analysis). [windows only]

pyaudio_portaudio is a fork of [PyAudio](https://pypi.org/project/PyAudio/), extending the latter with support for Windows sound loopback. Unfortunately it is not hosted on PyPI.